# iPhone 5c Provisioning on Xcode 6 Beta 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, macos

I have just recently registered into Apple developer program.
I have two Xcode environment - 
(1) Xcode version 5.1.1 
(2) Xcode Version 6.0 (6A279r) or Xcode 6.0 - Beta 6

I am trying to provision my Apple iPhone 5c ( running iOS 7.1) for development purpose, hence I followed the following steps:
(1) Connected the iPhone 5c  to USB port of my MacBook Pro Retina Laptop ( OS X 10.9.4)
(2) Opened Xcode 6.0 - Beta 6 and then selected Windows -> Devices menu

I can see that Xcode 6.0-Beta 6 is detecting my iPhone 5c, however I do not see a "Use for Development" option. 
 So I decided to try it on Xcode 5.1.1 version.

(3) launched Xcode 5.1.1 
(4) Opened Windows->Organizer - Devices Tab 

I could see that Xcode 5.1.1 is providing me option to provision my Apple iPhone 5c for development purpose.

So why is it that Xcode 6.0 ( Beta 6) is not giving me the option to provision my iPhone 5c for development ? 
 Is it because it need iOS 8 installed on iPhone 5c ? 
Or do I need to do the manual provisioning for Xcode 6.0 - beta 6 ?

Comment: Why are you still using Xcode 6 beta? Upgrade to 6.0.1 and try it

Comment: Also if I decide to register the iPhone 5c for local development and testing purpose in Xcode 5.1.1, would it create problem for me later while using Xcode 6 - beta 6 ? Is it possible to use iPhone 5c for local development and testing on two version of Xcode ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the "use for development button" simply registers the devices UUID with your apple developer account. From my quick testing in xcode 6 there is no longer a button to hit to do this and instead if you try running an app on a connected phone that doesn't have a UUID registered with your account it will spit you through a few dialog boxes and register it.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to deploy my app and see what happens.

Comment: Yes. You are right. I am running my App on iPhone now.

Comment: The whole iOS provisioning system can be quiet confusing. Luckily apple has done a lot lately to help ease some of the headache by making xcode handle almost everything for you. If you want to distribute your app to others for testing I recommend you look into a service called testflight, it makes deploying your apps for testing so incredibly easy and painfree.